# Wordpress 6.3 - how to get a custom post type object by ID using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am getting a new object (about 20 objects) from a remote API each time my map moves on the user's screen from mapbox each representing a ski mountain.  Locally, I have a custom post type that matches the same objects that come from mapbox which contains potential override data.  For example, one field that comes from mapbox is the URL of the website, which if blank, I would like to use the locally stored value.  Alternatively, even if mapbox gave me a URL and there is an override value locally, I would like to use the override value.  The remote object is stored in skiMtnData (about 300 mountains in total or 300 objects to loop through).  skiMtnData[i].properties will give me each ski mountain object.  skiMtnData[i].properties.name will give me the mountain's name, for example.  skiMtnData[i].properties.url will give me the mountain's url.  The locally stored override data is stored in a custom post type call overRideData.  In overRideData, I have match fields of name, url, etc.  Both skiMtnData and overRideData have a unique key called ID that match.

What is the simplest way to fetch the local data from the custom post type based in ID?  Here is the beginning of the loop.

```
/** javascript **/
for ( var i=0, ien=skiMtnData.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
    console.log(skiMtnData[i].properties); // prints the entire mountain object
    console.log(skiMtnData[i].properties.name); // prints the name of the mountain
    // here how should I get the local custom post type data by ID?
}
```

Any pointers very welcome.

Comment: You could use AJAX to request the info from the server then do what you need to with it on success.